# Boot issue with Win7 (ntfs) and Ubuntu 14.04 (ext4) on separate hard drives

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi

I have two internal SSDs connected to my motherboard's SATA slots with OS's installed as written in the title. Whether I connect the Win7 or Ubuntu HD as the primary one, I do not see the other HD in the UEFI boot menu even though it's physically connected to the motherboard. Both OS's recognize the drives after booting (e.g., I get a drive menu button on the taskbar in Ubuntu). My goal is to dual boot without manually plugging and unplugging the drives.

[Bootinfoscript result](http://paste.ubuntu.com/16332739/)

Comment: Please run the [Boot Info Script](https://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/). This will generate a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post that file to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us more details about your configuration, which is required to base an answer on more than guesswork.

Comment: @RodSmith I put up a pastebin link

Comment: You have BIOS boot for both drives with both as MBR partitioned. Windows only boots from MBR with BIOS, so if you convert to gpt you also have to reinstall to be UEFI boot. Ubuntu can boot in either UEFI or BIOS from gpt drives but should normally be BIOS boot from MBR partitioned drives. Your UEFI/BIOS should show both drives. If not it is an issue in your UEFI/BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why this is the case, but if I use F2 to get to the BIOS and then look at what drive I can boot, I only see the Windows one, as I've said in my question. However, I have found that if I hold shift during boot-up and then press F11, I can choose either drive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UEFI boot make sure your partition table GPT formatted. You did not mention which bootloader you are using, but you should update the grub. `sudo update-grub`.

I found this on [microsoft site](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh824839.aspx):

> When you deploy Windows® to a UEFI-based PC, you must format the hard drive that includes the Windows partition by using a GUID partition table (GPT) file system. Additional drives may use either the GPT or the master boot record (MBR) file format.

So yes, you probably need to convert your partition from MBR to GPT. But before you start it you check this below:

I did some google search and I found [this](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=171139). It may help you. Further instructions:

- turn off "fastboot" in Windows 8
- disable "Secure Boot" in the BIOS
- update grub

Enter in BIOS. You should see both SDD in the boot sequence list.
If you can't find both of them, you should update your BIOS.

After the update you still can't find them, may your SSD is fragmented or your motherboard has driver issue.

Comment: My partitions are MBR. Do I have to change them to GPT to dual boot? Do I have to change both hard drives to GPT?

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to configure GRUB to chainload to the Windows boot loader. If you installed Ubuntu after Windows and if both drives were plugged in when you did that, this *should have* been set up automatically. If either of those conditions was not met, you should be able to fix it as follows:

1. Connect both hard disks.
2. Boot to Ubuntu
3. Open a Terminal window.
4. Type `sudo update-grub`.

This should update the GRUB menu to get both OSes in the GRUB menu, which should appear the next time you reboot.